# Use rank for different columns

Tags: sql, oracle, rank

my table looks like this:

```
CITY     TOPIC      RANK
NY       FOOTBALL   1
NY       BASKETBALL 2
....
NY       BASEBALL   10
WS       FOOTBALL   1
....
```

What I want is this:

```
CITY     TOP 1      TOP 2      ...      TOP 10
NY       FOOTBALL   BASKETBALL ...      BASEBALL
WS       FOOTBALL   ............................
```

How can I do that? Thank you very much!

Comment: Google "SQL pivot query"

Comment: I'm not sure that search string applies to Oracle.

Comment: @DanBracuk - why not try it and resolve your uncertainty? Pivot has been a feature of Oracle SQL since 11gR1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply use conditional aggregation:

```
select city,
       max(case when rank = 1 then topic end) as top_1,
       max(case when rank = 2 then topic end) as top_2,
       . . . 
       max(case when rank = 10 then topic end) as top_10
from t
group by city;
```

This assumes that `rank` has no ties.  If you have ties, you might prefer `listagg()` instead of `max()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct Pivot up in MySQL.
You need to create columns manually in Query.
For Example

`select City, 
max(case when Rank=1 then TopiC end) as Top1,
max(case when Rank=2 then Topic end) as Top2,
. 
. 
.
max(case when Rank=10 then Topic end) as Top10 
from Table group by City`

Comment: It's Oracle SQL :-) But then Ill do it the way you say.

Comment: "NOT A VALID GROUP BY EXPRESSION" :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT City,Topic, 
 'Top '+ cast(Rank as varchar(10)) AS TopRank
 FROM TableName
 ) T
PIVOT 
(
max(topic) 
FOR TopRank IN ([Top 1], [Top 2],[Top 10])
) as pvt
```